# Can I execute dynamic sql with sas?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sas

I have a complex **dynamic sql** query that  I execute in t-sql on a sql server. I know you can use SAS to execute simple SQL Select queries. But can you execute dynamic SQL in SAS? Can you execute dynamic SQL remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can connect to the server in PROC SQL and execute commands directly on the SQL server.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/65065/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0tpd3yaqvep53n1g8wahav3hgco.htm